# Can I use a JWT as an anti-CSRF Token

Tags: security, jwt, csrf, csrf-token

I want to see if I can accomplish preventing CSRF while not having to store any additional information in a users session in redis on the server. Upon requesting the form to delete an account, can I sign a JWT token using a random string (uuid4) and secret also with an expiration time and send the result to the client. When the form is submitted I will verify the JWT.

Something like this:

```
const tokenToSend = jwt.sign(uuid4(), SECRET, { expire: 60 })
```

Comment: Does your `jwt.sign` function update or add a timestamp the JWT _before_ it's signed? If not, then your idea is actually terrible for security because then all of the CSRF tokens will be the same for each user.

Comment: If you are using REST API and content-type: Application/Json or some non simple content types,
Then probably you don't need to implement CSRF protection. You can make use of CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: @CyberSrikanth would you say that CSRF tokens are a thing of the past when we now have CORS and same-site cookies?

Comment: @Numnumberry It depends... For example, If you try to submit form data from a differnt site (site that not in allowed origin), CORS will prevent javascript from reading the response, but it wont block the request (request can still succeed) and it is possible for CSRF attack. You can replace CSRF tokens with CORS, But not always, It depends on your use case. You should not accept simple content types such as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and use only types like `application/json` which requires `OPTIONS` pre-flight call to make sure this method is allowed.

Comment: @Numnumberry I'm not sure, I hope this would help you (https://cyber-srikanth.blogspot.com/2020/08/csrf-token-vs-cors-in-spa.html)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to describe Csrf attack is that the victim (who has login a vulnerable website A) browser a third webside B which did a request pretented as the victim to website A.
So to prevent csrf attack, we have to set the requests (that we want to protect) not predictable so that the attacker can't prepare the requests before. If you use jwt as csrf token you have to make this jwt unique for every request.